# Eclipse Che - Server wont start on Windows

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-che

I'm trying to install eclipse che on my windows 8. I have all the required environment variables in place. Docker is up and running on VM. but when i run

```
$: Che run
```

It wont start. Please check the image below for reference.

[image]

che.properties config file

```
che.user.workspaces.storage=${che.home}/workspaces
che.machine.projects.internal.storage=/projects
che.conf.storage=${catalina.base}/temp/local-storage
che.ide.context=ide
project.template_location_dir=${che.home}/templates
project.template_descriptions_dir=${che.home}/templates

oauth.github.clientid=***
oauth.github.clientsecret=***
oauth.github.authuri= https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize
oauth.github.tokenuri= https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token
oauth.github.redirecturis= http://localhost:${SERVER_PORT}/ide/api/oauth/callback
auth.oauth.access_denied_error_page=/error-oauth
user.self.creation.allowed=false
notification.server.propagate_events=
schedule.core_pool_size=10

machine.docker.registry=http://192.168.99.100:5000
docker.registry.auth.url=http://192.168.99.100:5000
docker.registry.auth.username=user1
docker.registry.auth.password=pass
docker.registry.auth.email=user1@email.com

docker.connection.tcp.connection_timeout_ms=600000
docker.connection.tcp.read_timeout_ms=600000
machine.server.ext.archive=${che.home}/lib/ws-agent.zip
machine.server.terminal.archive=${che.home}/lib/terminal
machine.logs.location=${che.logs.dir}/machine/logs
machine.default_mem_size_mb=1024
machine.supported_docker_version=1.6.0,1.6.1,1.6.2,1.7.1,1.8.1
machine.ws_agent.max_start_time_ms=60000
machine.ws_agent.ping_delay_ms=2000
machine.ws_agent.ping_conn_timeout_ms=2000
machine.docker.machine_extra_hosts=NULL
machine.docker.che_api.endpoint=http://che-host:8080/ide/api

machine.docker.pull_image=true
machine.docker.local_node_host=http://192.168.99.100:5000
api.endpoint=http://localhost:${SERVER_PORT}/ide/api

org.everrest.asynchronous=false
org.everrest.asynchronous.pool.size=20
org.everrest.asynchronous.queue.size=500
org.everrest.asynchronous.job.timeout=10
org.everrest.asynchronous.cache.size=1024
org.everrest.asynchronous.service.path=/async/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the nature of the way virtualbox is configured to use Docker Machine on your computer. We'll need some more details on your configuration. Can you post a question on GitHub issues at github.com/eclipse/che?

Something you can test.

1. docker-machine rm default
2. Start che a second time - and see if that fixes the issue

I don't think the che.properties is your configuration issue. This seems like something with virtualbox.  Please post an issue to /github.com/eclipse/che for tracking & discussion.

Comment: As you said, I'm missing something with docker configuration. My docker is running on VM. Is anywhere I can get detailed che.properties configurations?